# CorePlot legend displays but no names are shown

Tags: core-plot

When my bar chart displays I see an area for the legend as it's showing the little colored squares for each plot, but there's no text next to the colored square.  I'm sure it's because I've done my method wrong.  This is how I get the titles:

```swift
func legendTitleForBarPlot(barPlot: CPTBarPlot, recordIndex idx: UInt) -> String? {
    guard let ident = barPlot.identifier as? String else { return nil }
    guard alreadyPrintedLegend[ident] == nil else { return nil }

    alreadyPrintedLegend[ident] = true

    return ident
}
```

When my plots are created I set the identifier to the name of the plot that I want displayed.  If I put some print statements above I do see each plot name being printed once.

Comment: Does it work without this method? By default, the plot will use the `identifier` for the legend title if it is a string.

Comment: Yes, taking that out solves my issue.  Thanks!  Really appreciate the great support you provide for this product!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not implement the delegate method and the legend will show properly.

I put this as an answer so when people are searching they see this was resolved.